# Python3's equivalent to BASH's bashrc

Tags: bash, python-3.x

I have been searching the Internet and my hard-drive trying to see if Python3 has an equivalent to BASH's ~/.bashrc file. The reason I need one is so I can have certain functions be defined as soon as I open Guake which I configured to use Python3.

For example, with such a file, I can add this function

```
def CLEAR(): os.system(['clear','cls'][os.name == 'nt'])
```

to such a file. Then, when I open Guake, I can use Python and type CLEAR() when I want to clear the terminal. Otherwise, I need to make the function every time I use it the first time in a Guake session and I am very lazy on some days (^u^).

So, the question is what goes in this blank:

BASH is to ~/.bashrc or /etc/bashrc as Python3 is to **__**

sh - ~/.bashrc      = Python3 - ?
def CLEAR(): os.system(['clear','cls'][os.name == 'nt'])

Comment: Do you want `CLEAR` function is defined for Python interactive session?

Comment: @falsetru, yes I want CLEAR() to be defined in the interactive session. I also have other functions and variables that I want pre-set in the interactive session.

Comment: No up-votes? I thought this was a very clever question. Does it need improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a file (for example ~/.pythonstartup)

```
import os

def CLEAR():
    os.system(['clear', 'cls'][os.name == 'nt')
```

Set the environmental variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to reference above file. Put that into ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonstartup
```

See [The Interactive Startup File in Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file)

Answer (score 2):

Python is more flexible, you want to set the `$PYTHONSTARTUP` variable to the pathname of your start up file